# Something to convert a makefile.am to project in Visual Studio (2005)

Tags: windows, make, conversion

I'm interested in porting a library to Windows so that I can contribute to this library's project. This library has a Makefile.am, and I can sort of figure out how the library should be built (but I'm fairly new to the concept of makefiles). I was wondering if there is an automatic way to translate a Makefile.am into something that Visual Studio 2005 can use.

What I know so far:

I do see that there are directives in the library's Makefile.am for building to a Windows target (i.e `if BUILD_WINDOWS ...some stuff... endif`).

I also know that there's AutoMake for Windows, which generates the Makefile.in from the .am, but I have a knowledge gap as to how this Makefile.in would then be used. (Still researching this avenue).

Is my only course to convert the makefile manually into a VS2005 project? It seems like it is easier to convert from Windows to Linux, but that may be just my imagination.

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

For the makefile.in / makefile.am relation, have a look at the wikipedia on the GNU build system: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_build_system. There's a graph explaining the role of each file.
There's no automated way that I know of, but I can recommend you too ways to be able to compile the library:

- Install cygwin: http://www.cygwin.com that comes with the full GNU system and many useful utilities
- Migrate the project to use cmake (http://www.cmake.org). CMake can generate Microsoft VS files as well as Unix Makefiles. This project: http://cvs.savannah.gnu.org/viewvc/tsp/?root=tsp uses cmake a builds on Windows and various Unix flavors, for example.